# Setting css property in decimals / floating with javascript

Tags: javascript, css

when i use `element.style.left = 1.6px;` this only sets property to 1. Not 1.6px. Which is not right. Is there a way to do this correctly.

Only i can think of is add new stylesheet to the whole body and delete the old one...seems like too much though.

Comment: write it as a string, `'1.6px';`

Comment: There is no such thing as .6 pixels. Pixels are **always** an integer.

Comment: @Scott While your logic may seem right to you, that is not entirely true, check this fiddle and see computed styles for `div.wrap`  - http://jsfiddle.net/easwee/bssnY/  - you will see that it computes to `301.5px` and renders as `302px` on screen (because of rounding). Decimals DO sum up AND rounding occurs at render.

Comment: the problem i was trying to solve doesn't exist...just writing what i have written would give error..i meant to put quotes but what i thought was that value gets converted from 1.6px to 1. Not because style.left is like that but because parseInt was messing it up.

Comment: all i had to do is user parsefloat instead of parseint...when it's 3 in night things like this happen

Comment: @easwee -- *"...and renders as `302px`"*  because there's no such thing as a partial pixel :) I did not state you couldn't specify partial pixels. You can. They just don't actually exist.

Comment: ok so you can set it to 1.5, you will get 1.5, but it will render rounded...like 2 here. ALso if you zoom in the difference shows up.

Comment: I was hoping partial pixel would mean antialiasing kicking in. like if it's 3 pixels then 3 pixels are lit up...but if its 3.5 then 3 are fully lit up but 4th one is half lit up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
element.style.left = "1.6px";
```

Because css properties are strings in Javascript.

Comment: Consider adding a bit of explanation to your answer. For example why are the quote marks required...?

Answer (score 0):

This is because we can't operate on anything other than multiples of 1 pixel in CSS. Think of the page as a grid of pixels - we can't write between the lines of the grid! Why is it that you need 1.6px specifically?

Comment: no actually http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html and http://alistapart.com/article/a-pixel-identity-crisis/